# clone File object with offset

Tags: ruby, file-io, clone

Consider the following script:

```
f = File.open('1.txt')
puts f.gets
f2 = f.clone
puts f.gets
puts f2.gets || '<empty line>'
```

`1.txt` is like this:

```
first line
second line
third line
...
```

When I run it, my output is:

```
first line
second line
<empty line>
```

Desired output is:

```
first line
second line
second line
```

Is it even possible?

**UPD** In fact, I'm reading a file from end to start with `elif`. So I decided to first find out how to do it with reading a file from start to end, considering I couldn't find a way to do even that.

I've got a log file lie this:

```
<timestamp> app from <path> restarted with PID <pid>
<timestamp> <pid> <some info>
<timestamp> <pid> <some info>
<timestamp> app from <path> restarted with PID <pid>
<timestamp> <pid> <some info>
<timestamp> <pid> <some info>
```

The log is used by several applications. And I'm trying to filter out what one of them is doing. Applications are restarted from time to time. So first I need to determine last application pid, then inspect all the rows until it's restarted, determine next pid, and so on.

**UPD2** Here's what I'm trying to do now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'elif'
f = Elif.open('/home/yuri/_/1.txt')
def f.dup
    p self
    file = instance_variable_get(:@file)
    r = Elif.open file.path
    r.instance_variable_get(:@file).seek file.pos
    instance_variables.select{ |n| n != :@file }.each{ |n|
        p n
        r.instance_variable_set n, instance_variable_get(n)
    }
    p r
    r
end
p f.gets
f2 = f.dup
p f.gets
p f2.gets
```

But the output surprisingly as follows:

```
"fourth line\n"
#<Elif:0x007f7842b1fa28 @file=#<File:/home/yuri/_/1.txt>, @current_pos=0, @read_size=1024, @line_buffer=["1\n", "2\n", "3\n"]>
:@current_pos
:@read_size
:@line_buffer
#<Elif:0x007f7842b1f1b8 @file=#<File:/home/yuri/_/1.txt>, @current_pos=0, @read_size=1024, @line_buffer=["1\n", "2\n", "3\n"]>
"third line\n"
"second line\n"
```

Could someone shed some light on it? Are both `@file`s connected to the same file descriptor?

**UPD3** It works in start-to-end direction though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
f = File.open('/home/yuri/_/1.txt')
def f.dup
    r = File.open path
    r.seek pos
    r
end
p f.gets
f2 = f.dup
p f.gets
p f2.gets
```

Output:

```
"1\n"
"2\n"
"2\n"
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, but not by cloning the File object which is just wrapping a stream.  What exactly are the requirements here?

Comment: I don't understand the point of `f2`, which is simply a copy of the file handle, which does not change.  Did you mean something like `puts (f2 = gets)`?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland That was my attempt to create second `File` instance with the same non-empty offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If moving in start-to-end direction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
f = File.open('/home/yuri/_/1.txt')
def f.dup
    r = File.open path
    r.seek pos
    r
end
p f.gets
f2 = f.dup
p f.gets
p f2.gets
```

Output:

```
"1\n"
"2\n"
"2\n"
```

If moving backwards:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'elif'
f = Elif.open('/home/yuri/_/1.txt')
def f.dup
    file = instance_variable_get(:@file)
    r = Elif.open file.path
    r.instance_variable_get(:@file).seek file.pos
    instance_variables.select{ |n| n != :@file }.each{ |n|
        r.instance_variable_set n, begin
            instance_variable_get(n).dup
        rescue TypeError => e
            # !!! not sure about the following line
            raise unless e.message == "can't dup %s" % instance_variable_get(n).class.name
            instance_variable_get(n)
        end
    }
    r
end
p f.gets
f2 = f.dup
p f.gets
p f2.gets
```

Output:

```
"4\n"
"3\n"
"3\n"
```

`1.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
```